# Subtract sample from list, update average

Tags: c++, math, average, stdmap

I have a map defined as:

```
std::map<float, std::map<unsigned short, int>>
```

The float value is the value of which I keep an average value. Fx a speed. The short is an identifier fx a date. The integer is a count, which I also keep track of. The count says how many samples there have been, with that specific value. Eg. On this date, I have a 'bin' with the values of 220 km/h. The count for this could be 2132.

In case I add a new sample, e.g. a car that drove 220, it then falls in a specific 'bin' for that speed and day, I update the average and count as following:

```
    count++;
    average = average + ((samplevalue - average) / count);
```

This seems to work fine, the average is updated.

But my problem is when I want to remove entries for a specific identifier, e.g. day.

```
for (auto& bin : *containerMap_)
{
    auto iter = bin.second.find(currentDay);
    if (iter != bin.second.end())
    {

        average = (( average  * count) - iter->first) / (count - (iter->second));
        meassurementCount -= iter->second;

        bin.second.erase(iter);

    }
}
```

Here `iter->first` is the value of the bin (speed) and `iter->second` is the count.

Though when I delete for a specific identifier, the average is not updated as expected. 
In my testcase i only insert samples with one speed, so I only have one bin. Each speed is 3, so I expect the average to keep being 3. It does so with insert, but when I try to remove from one identifier (day),  the average is updated to:

```
Avg : 3.00139
```

Why does that calculation not work? I would really hate to itterate through everything to update the average, since the count could be in billions.

Best regards :)

Comment: i think the problem is, that you only remove iter->first once, even when its count is > 1. So the Problem with `average = (( average  * count) - iter->first) / (count - (iter->second));` should be solved, if you write `average = (( average  * count) - iter->second*iter->first) / (count - (iter->second));` . Without testing it ...

Comment: You should really use intermediate variables. `iter->first` is the date, not the speed. `bin.first` is the speed. Also where's the definition of `count`?!